# How to use a token that includes slashes with PathAuto?

Tags: 9, path-aliases

I have a custom token that gets the `path` value from a [JSON field](https://www.drupal.org/project/json_field).  The JSON field stores the path like this (in the database, the slashes are escaped, but I'm showing an unescaped example here):

```
{ "path": "a/b/c" }
```

Every node contains this JSON field, so I made a custom token, `[mymodule:json_path]`.

I then set this token as the path for nodes on the PathAuto patterns page (`/admin/config/search/path/patterns`).

However, PathAuto is stripping the slashes, so when I save a node, I get the path `abc` when I want `a/b/c`.

Elsewhere, when I use the token, I get the value with unescaped slashes as expected (for example, `a/b/c`); I know this because if I set a metatag on the node to the token, the expected value appears.

Also, if I disable **Generate automatic URL alias** and manually set the path to `/a/b/c`, then I get the expected path of `/a/b/c`.

So, how can I get PathAuto not to remove the slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through the UI, at /admin/config/search/path/settings.

Scroll down to "Punctuation" at the bottom, expand it, find the *Slash (/)* option near the end of the list, and set it to something other than *Remove*.

[image]

Comment: If needed, you can fine-tune the behavior with `hook_pathauto_alias_alter()`.

Answer (score 1):

In `admin/config/search/path/settings`, add your custom token to Safe Tokens.

[image]